# string.find using directory path in Lua

Tags: perl, string, lua

I need to translate this piece of code from Perl to Lua

```
open(FILE, '/proc/meminfo');   
while(<FILE>)  
{  
    if (m/MemTotal/)  
    {  
        $mem = $_;  
        $mem =~ s/.*:(.*)/$1/;
    }  
    elseif (m/MemFree/)
    {
        $memfree = $_;
        $memfree =~ s/.*:(.*)/$1/;
    }
}
close(FILE);
```

So far I've written this

```
while assert(io.open("/proc/meminfo", "r")) do
    Currentline = string.find(/proc/meminfo, "m/MemTotal")
    if Currentline = m/MemTotal then
        Mem = Currentline
        Mem = string.gsub(Mem, ".*", "(.*)", 1)
    elseif m/MemFree then
        Memfree = Currentline
        Memfree = string.gsub(Memfree, ".*", "(.*)", 1)
    end
end
io.close("/proc/meminfo")
```

Now, when I try to compile, I get the following error about the second line of my code

```
luac: Perl to Lua:122: unexpected symbol near '/'
```

obviously the syntax of using a directory path in string.find is not like how I've written it. 'But how is it?' is my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To iterate a file line by line you can use `io.lines`.

```
for line in io.lines("/proc/meminfo") do
    if line:find("MemTotal") then --// Syntactic sugar for string.find(line, "MemTotal")
        --// If logic here...
    elseif --// I don't quite understand this part in your code.
    end
end
```

No need to close the file afterwards.

Comment: Glad to help. If you're planning on coding in Lua further I recommend reading Programming in Lua, its first edition is available free online at http://www.lua.org/pil/.

Comment: I am in possession of Beggining Lua Programming by k.Jung and A.Brown, which is a very good book with the best index I have seen in a textbook. Trouble is, before I was tasked with translating about 300 lines of Perl to Lua, I had never done either of them, so I'm learning them both in parallel.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to stick to Perl's control flow. Lua has a very nice "gmatch" function which allows you to iterate over all possible matches in a string. Here's a function which parses /proc/meminfo and returns it as a table:

```
function get_meminfo(fn)
    local r={}
    local f=assert(io.open(fn,"r"))
    -- read the whole file into s
    local s=f:read("*a")
    -- now enumerate all occurances of "SomeName: SomeValue"
    -- and assign the text of SomeName and SomeValue to k and v
    for k,v in string.gmatch(s,"(%w+): *(%d+)") do
            -- Save into table:
        r[k]=v
    end 
    f:close()
    return r
end
-- use it
m=get_meminfo("/proc/meminfo")
print(m.MemTotal, m.MemFree)
```